# ¿Se puede interpretar como verdadera la declaración de Cospedal de que "el PP sigue siendo el partido favorito de todos los españoles"?

Tags: gramática, significado, españa, redacción, interpretación

Ayer en las noticias hablaron de la [última encuesta de intención de voto del CIS](http://www.cis.es/cis/opencms/ES/NoticiasNovedades/InfoCIS/2017/Documentacion_3164.html) (Centro de Investigaciones Sociológicas), en las cuales se arrojaba el siguiente resultado para España:

```
33%     PP
21,7%   Podemos
18,6%   PSOE
12,4%   C's
```

Ante estos resultados, la señora María Dolores de Cospedal, actual ministra de Defensa, [declaró](http://www.cuatro.com/noticias/espana/Cospedal-PP-favorito-espanoles-importante_0_2320500453.html):

> **El PP sigue siendo el partido favorito de todos los españoles.**

A mí esta frase me parece falsa, porque para mucha gente no es su partido favorito. Concretamente a los que prefieren votar antes a cualquier otro partido. De hecho, ni siquiera es el partido favorito de la mayoría de los españoles, porque solo les votarían uno de cada tres (33%). Así que mi pregunta es, y dado que los políticos tienden a cuidar las cosas que dicen: ¿hay alguna forma en la que la frase se pudiera interpretar como verdadera?

Comment: Centrémonos en la 2ª acepción de [favorito](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Hh5BEDz): _Que tiene, en la opinión general, la mayor probabilidad de ganar en una competición_. Si consideramos "ganar unas elecciones" como ser el que más votos recibe, allí sería cierto. Esto deja de lado quién puede gobernar (alianzas [postelectorales](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/poselectoral-y-postelectoral-se-escriben-en-una-palabra-1142/)).

Comment: Iba a decir lo mismo que fedorqui, la frase es "correcta", no se le puede pedir más. Analizar lo que dice un político es analizar lo que dice un Sofista: solo importa la retórica y el efecto de la falacia en las personas que van a votar, después de eso solo hay vacío; buscar en lo que dicen alguna verdad más allá de lo más estrictamente básico (que lo hace "correcto"), es un esfuerzo inútil: sus palabras no tuvieron nunca esa intención, desde su concepción hasta que salen por esa bocaza que tienen.

Comment: @fedorqui entiendo entonces que la frase se puede dar por válida con esa acepción, es como si al final de la frase se hubiera omitido "para ganar las próximas elecciones".

Comment: Yo creo que el problema de esa frase es la palabra _todos_, si hubiera dicho «El PP sigue siendo el partido favorito de los españoles» podría considerarse correcto según la acepción de favorito que comenta @fedorqui, pero no es el partido favorito de **todos** los españoles.

Comment: @Nox ¿noto un cierto resquemor hacia la clase política? :D A mí la política cada día me deja más frío, pero aun así considero que analizar las cosas que dicen los políticos es un ejercicio interesante. Hay algunos que [no dan puntada sin hilo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UfJLVjc#D6g6BrM).

Comment: @blonfu se podría interpretar, tal vez, como que "todos los españoles han  determinado que el PP es el favorito [para ganar las elecciones]", aunque estoy de acuerdo contigo en que la frase chirría un poco al incluir ese "todos", tal y como está.

Comment: Yo coincido con lo que ha dicho fedorqui: la frase da a entender que el PP es "el partido ganador". Dado que ha sacado el mayor porcentaje de intención de voto y obviando convenientemente las diferencias que hay siempre entre las encuestas y la realidad, desde un punto de vista estrictamente lógico esta conclusión es correcta. El "todos" que escama, es una simple referencia a que esta encuesta es supuestamente válida para todos los españoles (desde luego, esto sería otro tema igualmente largo de discutir), que "casualmente" refuerza la idea, y por tanto el sentimiento de victoria generado...

Comment: ... por la frase. Es una falacia _ad populum_ arquetípica, un "_semos los mejores y qué_" de toda la vida para espolear a los ya votantes del PP e intentar animar a los que están al borde del abismo. Referente a mi aversión a los políticos, es legendaria y totalmente merecida :D El problema es que me sé todos sus trucos "de pe a pa", eso solo consigue que cada vez que abren la boca todos esos trucos sucios me lleguen como bofetadas, así que cada vez que oigo o leo a un político solo consigo enervarme y reforzar esa aversión. Eso desde que aprendí lo que eran los sofistas, hace más de 20 años.

Comment: @Nox comparto tu hartazgo :) Sugeriría, sin embargo, que intentemos centrarnos en la parte lingüística de la frase, que es el ámbito de la pregunta que la hace interesante y apropiada para este sitio. Luego cuando lleguemos a una conclusión podemos convocar una rueda de prensa y rebatir la frase a Cospedal, si se da el caso ;-)

Comment: @fedorqui Totalmente correcto. Mis disculpas, me dejé llevar por la enervación que me provocan estas cosas. Dejémoslo en la lógica de la frase que comentaba antes y el argumento de la falacia _ad populum_ :)

Comment: Y si ahora ya convertís los comentarios en respuestas, conseguimos que la pregunta salga en las [_Hot Network Questions_](http://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot) y lo petamos. :D

Comment: Pues tenías razón, Carlos: [ya está](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5WgL.png) en las Hot Network Questions.

Comment: @fedorqui ¡a ver si atraemos visitas y usuarios, que me parece que [el anuncio en Travel](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4293/community-promotion-ads-2017/4314#4314) no está teniendo mucha aceptación! :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La frase es:

> El PP sigue siendo el partido favorito de todos los españoles.

Si tomamos la segunda acepción de [*favorito*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Hh5BEDz) del DRAE:

> 2. adj. Que tiene, en la opinión general, la mayor probabilidad de ganar en una competición. U. t. c. s.

Podríamos decir que la autora de la frase querría decir exactamente:

> El PP sigue siendo el partido *con la mayor probabilidad de ganar*.

Lo que tendría sentido, pues se puede definir "ganar las elecciones" como "ser el que obtenga el mayor número de votos", independientemente de quién acabe gobernando (por aquello de las alianzas postelectorales y demás).

---

Lo que chirría y considero incorrecto, y esto se comentó acertadamente en los comentarios, es la parte *de todos los españoles*. En concreto, el *todos*.

Una rápida mirada en el diccionario nos indica que [*todo*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZxVCoJq) quiere decir *totalidad*, *la totalidad del conjunto*, *cada*, etc. En cualquier caso, su uso en la frase viene a decir:

> El PP sigue siendo el partido favorito de todos y cada uno de los españoles.

lo cual es tremendamente falso y solo sería cierto si un 100% de los encuestados lo afirmara (y aún así, sería bueno matizar *de los encuestados* pues difícilmente 46 millones de personas pueden estar de acuerdo en algo).

Probablemente fue una manera algo confusa de decir:

> El PP sigue siendo el partido favorito, según los españoles.

---

Yendo más allá, observamos que la estimación del 33% está muy lejos de ser mayoría. En efecto, la suma de los otros porcentajes es superior, por lo que seguramente lo único que se puede afirmar es:

> El PP sigue siendo el partido con mayor intención de voto.

Que, unido a lo dicho anteriormente respecto el uso de *favorito*, podría convertirse en algo indudablemente cierto como:

> El PP sigue siendo el partido al que la mayor proporción de votantes de partidos daría soporte.

Y nada más.

---

Para ofrecer un caso más claro, imaginemos la típica frase de anuncio:

> Seis de cada diez dentistas recomiendan esta pasta de dientes.

De ella solamente se puede inferir un valor relativo:

> *La mayoría* de los dentistas recomienda...

Mientras que un valor absoluto es falso:

> *Todos* los dentistas recomiendan...

y solo sería cierto si todos los dentistas se manifestaran en el mismo sentido.

Comment: Por votación popular, la marca verde es tuya. :) ¡Buena respuesta!

Answer (score 5):

Escuché estas declaraciones de la secretaria general del PP (entiendo que en este caso hablaba en calidad de tal) y también me llamó la atención esta frase. Entiendo que no, la frase no se puede considerar como cierta por culpa de la palabra *todos*. Paso a analizarla.

La palabra *favorito*, como adjetivo, tiene dos acepciones según el DRAE:

1. Estimado y apreciado con preferencia.
2. Que tiene, en la opinión general, la mayor probabilidad de ganar en una competición.

Yo no conozco ningún otro uso de la palabra (como adjetivo, insisto) distinto de los que recoge el diccionario, así que daré estas acepciones por válidas.

El uso de una u otra acepción viene indicado por la preposición que sigue a la palabra *favorito*. Así:

> El PP es el partido favorito *de* los expertos.
>
> El PP es el partido favorito *para* los expertos.

En el primer caso, decimos que los expertos prefieren el PP frente a los demás partidos; en el segundo, decimos que los expertos consideran que el PP es el partido que tiene más probabilidades de ganar. Por tanto, Cospedal está utilizando la primera acepción.

Podríamos pensar que comete una incorrección gramatical y, en realidad, está intentando usar la segunda; en este caso, la frase no es cierta porque en la encuesta se pregunta a qué partido se tiene intención de votar (cuál es el preferido), no qué partido se cree que va a ganar unas hipotéticas elecciones. Esta pregunta también es habitual en las encuestas y se usa para *cocinar* los datos, pero no es la que aparece en los datos publicados. Así pues, supondré que la acepción pretendida es la primera: el PP es el partido que prefieren todos los españoles.

Y en este caso, como decía más arriba, la frase resulta falsa por el uso de *todos*. Si se hubiera dicho, simplemente:

> El PP sigue siendo el partido favorito de los españoles.

Entonces podríamos considerar que la frase es válida. Se puede argumentar si es correcto decir esto, siendo que la mayoría de los españoles (67 %) no lo consideran su favorito, pero ya entramos en un terreno más ambiguo del lenguaje. Sin embargo, al decir que es el favorito de *todos* los españoles, ya no. En este caso, la palabra *todos* significa *todos y cada uno*; con que hubiera un español que no lo considerara su favorito, la frase ya no sería cierta.

Comment: Gorpik, siempre te explicas fantásticamente.

Comment: Gracias, @fedorqui, pero después de publicar esto he visto que poco antes habías escrito algo parecido. Como el enfoque no es exactamente igual, prefiero que se queden las dos respuestas.

Answer (score 2):

Los usuarios Gorpik y fedorqui ya han dicho que desde el punto de vista de esa acepción de "favoritos" ya mencionada, la frase es correcta, por lo cual no voy a incidir más en ello... pero sí quería añadir algo respecto a ese "todos": en mi opinión no es simplemente una cuestión de si su significado es correcto literalmente, sino cómo afecta al que escucha la frase y que función tiene en el conjunto.

Como ya escribí en los comentarios de la pregunta, yo veo toda la frase como una típica falacia *ad populum*, un "*semos los mejores y qué*".
Como ya sabemos, estas cosas no se hacen para describir la realidad ni para ser correctas en cuanto a su significado, sino para despertar sentimientos, sentimientos que consigan una reacción impulsiva que no tenga en cuenta la lógica.

El uso de "todos", por tanto, no tiene la intención de incluir a todos los españoles en un sentido semántico literal, sino reforzar el sentimiento de victoria y de pertenencia al grupo, apoyándose para ello en ciertas ideas más extendidas de lo debido, como que la mayoría siempre tiene la razón y que los resultados de las estadísticas se pueden aplicar a toda la población invariablemente (cómo me recordó fedorqui, este no es el sitio para extenderse en este tipo de cosas, así que no opinaré sobre estas ideas).

Dicho lo cual, ¿es correcta la frase? Desde luego NO lo es si analizamos el significado literal de la frase, que emana del uso del lenguaje para su construcción, y que nos atañe en esta página.
Sin embargo, la retórica, las falacias y otras artimañas también son parte del lenguaje, por poco que nos guste a algunos, así que desde ese punto de vista a mí me parece bastante correcta.

Comment: xD Recibido y editado, he obviado ese último medio párrafo, creo que así será más sencillo y seguro, antes que intentar darle vueltas para tratar no salirse del tiesto con un argumento que ya se sale por sí mismo.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias Nox! Muy buena respuesta, por cierto.

Comment: Ciertamente, el objetivo de la frase no es la corrección lingüística, sino transmitir un mensaje. Y el mensaje lo transmite. Desde ese punto de vista, como bien dices, es correcta, pues ha conseguido su objetivo.

Comment: Esto me hace pensar que, cosa poco habitual en Carlos, el título de la pregunta y el cuerpo no se corresponden. En el título pregunta si la frase es *acertada*, mientras que en el cuerpo pregunta si se puede interpretar de alguna forma como *verdadera*. Verdadera no es, pero acertada, según el punto de vista.

Comment: Bueno, la culpa es de la misma frase. Ciertamente, *es* una falacia, y solo con eso encontrarse con estas paradojas ya es lo más normal, es decir, están hechas precisamente para eso... buscar una vuelta de tuerca a la realidad para obtener lo que convenga: si está bien o mal, si es fiel a la verdad o no, eso en realidad no importa. La misma falta de intención hace que estos extremos se difuminen, habría que salirse de lo lingüistico y llegar a la lógica; al fin y al cabo el lenguaje es una herramienta, cada uno la usa para lo que quiere, ya sea decir verdades, esconderlas o disfrazar mentiras.

Comment: @Gorpik perdón, tienes razón, igual voy a tener que matizar un poco el título...

Answer (score 1):

Por dar un poco más de juego a la pregunta, y siempre intentando mantenerme en el punto de vista puramente lingüístico (sin entrar en opiniones personales), propongo algunas formas en las que la frase podría ser correcta:

- La parte "todos los españoles" no se refiere a las personas:

  > El PP sigue siendo el partido favorito de [entre] todos los [partidos] españoles.
- La frase en realidad lleva signos de puntuación, omitidos en la declaración oral:

  > El PP sigue siendo el partido favorito, de todos los españoles.

  Así la frase tendría más bien el sentido de que es "el partido favorito" y además es "de todos los españoles".
- También se podría mirar así:

  > El PP sigue siendo el partido de todos los españoles favorito.

  Es decir, de entre todos los partidos que son de todos los españoles, es el favorito.

Comment: Entendiéndolo como un juego lingüístico, la primera opción que ofreces me parece la más defendible. Un poco retorcido, pero sí.

Comment: Sinceramente, en la universidad mis profesores de estadística me repitieron mil y una veces que hay que ser estricto cuando describes los resultados. Te lo repiten tantas veces que se te queda grabado _a fuego_. Para mí expresar los resultados de una encuesta con una frase casual como esa, no es solo una falacia, es una muestra de profunda ignorancia sobre el tema. Con lo cual, en mi opinión la frase no tiene por donde agarrarla, habría que tirarla a la basura pedir disculpas a todo el que haya estudiado estadística alguna vez y hacer una nueva. Todo eso considerando que la intención...

Comment: ... inicial era otra que no fuera la pura falacia, y por tanto el puro aprovechamiento político. En ese caso, para lo que nos atañe aquí y en mi opinión, está bien tal y como está.

Comment: @Gorpik mi intención con esta respuesta era, efectivamente, ser retorcido. :D