# ¿Es correcto el titular "Nadie juega menos que Paco Alcácer en el Barça" cuando otros jugadores de otros equipos juegan menos?

Tags: gramática, significado, españa, redacción, interpretación

Resulta que hay un futbolista del FC Barcelona (también conocido como Barça) que apenas juega con su equipo. Se llama Paco Alcácer y hoy un periódico deportivo lleva la noticia [*Nadie juega menos que Paco Alcácer en el Barça: 809 minutos*](http://futbol.as.com/futbol/2017/02/28/primera/1488311857_535992.html).

Cuando leí el titular, me chirrió. Así como está formulada, parece que se refiera a que "ningún jugador de toda la liga juega menos que esta persona". Sin embargo, el cuerpo la noticia indica que de entre los de este equipo, este es el jugador que menos minutos disputa. Es decir, seguro que hay jugadores de otros equipos que han jugado menos minutos y este texto se centra solamente en este equipo.

Por tanto, parece que el titular correcto debería ser:

> En el Barça, nadie juega menos que Paco Alcácer

Obviando la estudiada ambigüedad de los periódicos deportivos, ¿podríamos afirmar que la frase *Nadie juega menos que Paco Alcácer en el Barça* es verdadera y equivalente a *En el Barça, nadie juega menos que Paco Alcácer*?

Comment: Sigo con la idea lanzada por Carlos en [¿Se puede interpretar como verdadera la declaración de Cospedal de que “el PP sigue siendo el partido favorito de todos los españoles”?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19650/1674)

Comment: Interesante. Todo parece que depende de dónde pongas los paréntesis imaginarios: "Nadie juega menos que (Paco Alcácer en el Barça)" o "(Nadie juega menos que Paco Alcácer) en el Barça". La primera podría ser falsa ya que habrá equipos con jugadores que jueguen menos, y la segunda es verdadera como bien comentas. Cuanto menos la frase es ambigua.

Comment: Si se refiriera a que nadie de la liga juega menos que este jugador, sería más correcto algo así como "nadie juega menos que lo que Paco Alcácer (juega) en el Barça" o, más sencillo, "nadie juega menos que Paco Alcácer, del Barça".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo las oigo como equivalentes. Distinto sería si la frase fuera: *"Nadie juega menos que Paco Alcácer, del Barça."* O bien *"Nadie juega menos que Paco Alcácer, que juega en el Barça desde hace x años."*

En otras palabras, el complemento *en el Barça* no suena incidental (opcional) sino que delimita claramente la referencia. Igual que si dijésemos:

1. *Nadie disfruta más que yo la primavera en los parques de la ciudad.*
2. *Nadie disfruta más que yo la primavera cuando llueve.*
3. *Nadie disfruta más que yo la primavera al aire libre.*

Todos esos complementos al final de las frases especifican y recortan su significado.